# how to manage connection refuse error elasticsearc-kibana-nginx over docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, docker-compose, kibana

Maybe I made 6 hours googling for finding answer. But I couldn't find any solution for that. I want to up 1 node elasticsearch +1 kibana with nginx (for load balancing, proxy and security issue) But when docker create an error on kibana part.How can I host elasticsearch node-kibana with nginx by using below codes?

```
Error:Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/
```

Elasticsearch.yml :

```
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9200
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.graph.enabled: false
xpack.watcher.enabled: false
```

ElasticSearch Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.2
COPY ./config/elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml 
RUN elasticsearch-plugin  install analysis-kuromoji
```

kibana.yml:

```
---
# Default Kibana configuration from kibana-docker.

server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
elasticsearch.username: elastic
elasticsearch.password: changeme
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
```

Kibana Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.2
COPY ./config/kibana.yml /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
COPY entrypoint.sh /tmp/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/entrypoint.sh
RUN kibana plugin --install elastic/sense
CMD ["/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Wait for the Elasticsearch container to be ready before starting Kibana.
echo "Stalling for Elasticsearch"
while true; do
  nc -q 1 elasticsearch 9200 2>/dev/null && break
done
echo "Starting Kibana"
exec kibana
```

nginx.conf:

```
upstream elasticsearch {
  server 38.252.127.221:9200;
  keepalive 15;
}

upstream kibana {
  server 38.252.127.221:5601;
  keepalive 15;
}

server {
  listen 9200;

  location / {
    auth_basic           "Protected Elasticsearch";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
  }
}

server {
  listen 5601;
  location / {
    auth_basic           "Protected Kibana";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;
    proxy_pass  http://kibana;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
 elasticsearch:
container_name: esc
image: esi:1.0.0
build: ./es
volumes:
  - ./data/es:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
ports:
    - 9200:9200
expose:
    - 9300
kibana:
container_name: kibanac
image: kibanai:1.0.0
build: ./kibana
links:
  - elasticsearch
ports:
  - 5601:5601
nginx:
image: nginx:latest
restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  - ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro,Z
  - ./nginx/htpasswd.users:/etc/nginx/htpasswd.users:ro,Z
ports:
  - "8900:5601"
  - "8901:9200"

 depends_on:
  - elasticsearch
  - kibana
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `elasticsearch.yml` change the first line to:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Previously you were telling elasticsearch to listen on localhost only so any connections from other containers wont be working as expected because the elastic search service is not listening on other interfaces however when you set it to `0.0.0.0` you will make elasticsearch able to receive connections from other containers and you should not get the `Connection Refused` issue

Also note that you don't need to publish 9200, 5601 port as this will make anyone able to call them directly without going through nginx basic authentication.

> The next part below is out of the question scope but worth mentioning.

You might need to replace this part of your `entrypoint.sh`, which added below:

```
# Wait for the Elasticsearch container to be ready before starting Kibana.
echo "Stalling for Elasticsearch"
while true; do
  nc -q 1 elasticsearch 9200 2>/dev/null && break
done
```

By using [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) or [wait-for](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for), both your way and these scripts makes you able to wait for another connection to be available before starting another container's service.